# Blurry font on Macbook Pro 2017 Catalina with Dell P2419HC

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina, font

Just bought a new external monitor to use with my Macbook Pro. Video and everything else is sharp but the font/text on everything is blurry which really affects my work when I look at Excel sheets.

Tried removing font smoothing and restating my laptop but doesn't seem to work. Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because your Mac has a screen resolution of 2560x1600 but your external display, though twice the size, has a fraction of that resolution, a mere 1920x1080?

Answer (score 4):

Your MacBook Pro's native display has 219 pixels per inch.

Your Dell display has 92 pixels per inch.

Apple's font smoothing technology is designed for high-resolution displays. MacOS used to include code to improve text on low-res screens, but it was removed a while ago.

In short: yep, text will look crappy on displays without a high pixel density using macOS.

If you look at the "**Related**" panel on this webpage, you will see lots of similar queries and responses.